# umount of davfs2 mounted directory causes segfault on Fedora 31 (davfs2-1.5.5-1.fc31.x86_64)

Tags: segmentation-fault, webdav, umount

dmesg  shows :

[6086030.335354] umount.davfs[1583255]: segfault ...

Looks like  the issue in :

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1736871

which suggests  using   davfs2-1.5.6-1.fc30

How  can  I  build / get  a davfs2 which fixes this as in above bug ?

Answer (score 0):

Get from Test repo :

dnf install davfs2  --enablerepo=updates-testing --best